# C++ recursion to check if number contains a digit

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a recursive function which checks if a number N contains a digit K and outputs "Yes" or "No". This version shows "yes,yes,no,yes" for N=5565 and K=5.

```
int digit(int n, int k)
{
    if (n < 0)
        n = -1*n;
    if (n/10 > 0) {
        digit(n/10, k);
    }

    if(n % 10 == k) cout<<"yes"<<endl;
    else cout<<"no"<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    digit(5565, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is how can I show only one "Yes" or "No"

Comment: the code does not work?

Comment: Firstly your code won't compile like you think it will.

Comment: I have fixed the indentation. Perhaps it's clear now why it doesn't work as you intended? In any case, the issues are that you always print a result when `digit` is called, and you call digit again even if the result is yes. You need to move the "yes"/"no" output out of the `digit` function.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code?

Comment: A simple use of the debugger will tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: A simple search of "StackOverflow c++ recursive digit check" will list many examples of this assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conditions are wrong

```
  void digit(int n, int k)
  {
    if (n < 0)
      n = -1 * n;

    if (n % 10 == k)
    {
      cout << "Yes\n";
      return;
    }
    else if (n / 10 > 0)
       digit(n / 10, k);
    else
      cout << "no" << endl;
 }
```